# Where can I exchange a new lens without paying expensive shipping?

Tags: selling

Does anyone know where can I exchange my new Canon lens? I bought it two days ago, but I realized that it is not suitable for me. It's a Canon 100mm L macro lens. I bought it from Hong Kong, and to send back it is very expensive.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: And what might you want in exchange?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you happen to have a local friend who really wants that lens, you are going to be out some money here. It is likely that sending it back to the store you bought it from is going to be your best bet. You might be able to sell it to someone locally, but because you are not a legitimate store, no one will pay full price. That means you will probably not recover as much as you would with the return. This is even more true if you took it out of the box and tried it.

In the future:

- do more research before big purchases
- buy local if you have any doubt